# Launching i3lock when lid closed/power button pressed?

Tags: laptop, 15.04, macbook-pro, i3-wm

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 15.04 on a Mid-2010 13inch MacBook Pro and the i3 window manager (efficiency, woo).

I have everything working just like I did on MATE, except I want the screen to lock using i3lock with a custom background when I close the lid or press the power button. Is this possible? If so, how?